# I want to fetch states of multiple countries selected in form. Please help me with this

Tags: laravel

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
<label>Country:</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<select  id="country-dd" name="country" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
    @foreach ($countries as $data)
<option value="{{$data->id}}">{{$data->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
<label>State:</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<select id="state-dd" name="state" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">                        </select>                    
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
<label>City:</label>                        
<div class="col-sm-4">
<select id="city-dd" name="city" class="form-control" multiple="multiple"                        </select>
</div>
```

DropdownController:

```
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\Country;
    use App\Models\State;
    use App\Models\City;
    use App\Models\User;
    
    class DropdownController extends Controller
    {
        public function fetchState(Request $request)
    {
        $cnt = explode("','", $request->country_id);
        $data['states'] = State::whereIn("country_id",$cnt)->get(["name", "id"]);
        return response()->json($data);
    }
    
    public function fetchCity(Request $request)
    {
       $data['cities'] = City::where("state_id",$request->state_id)->get(["name", "id"])
        return response()->json($data);
    }
    }
```

This is my Dropdown Controller and blade file. I want to fetch states of multiple countries in dropdown. Please check the code and correct it if it is wrong.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: And where do you fetch the states?

Comment: What have you actually tried in order to pass the values from the functions to the selectboxes.

Comment: I think you need use ajax request, when you selected country. And fetchState need add to routes

Comment: If you select country `x` then state `a` and country `y` then state `b`  both selected?

Comment: @GertB. States will be fetched in Dropdown controller under fetchState method

Comment: @A.ANoman Yes I am getting country IDs but not state IDs

Comment: @Collin please check below
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#country-dd').on('change', function () {
                var idCountry = this.value;
                // alert(idCountry);
                $("#state-dd").html('');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{url('/fetch-states')}}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        country_id: idCountry,
                        _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                    },

Comment: You have to append your `state` and `city` data from `ajax` request

Comment: @A.ANoman Can you brief me how ?? I am new to laravel

Comment: Please share your ajax request code for `state` and `city` in your question not comment

Comment: @PavloMezhevikin That is already done. But If I select Country A and B. It should fetch state for both A and B. But it only fetches states for B (last selected).

Comment: @Newbie, Do you tried like `name="state[]"`?

Comment: @A.ANoman I am unable to edit the question
And yes I tried name="state[]"

Comment: in fetchState you check `$request->country_id`. I think need look on this side.. check what data in this parameters

Comment: @PavloMezhevikin It is giving error 500

Comment: sorry,  if you give js code, where you use ajax, i can help.. also check that the route exists

Comment: @PavloMezhevikin I cant put the whole ajax over here bcoz of limitations and not even edit the question. Can you suggest any other option??